# cudaThreadSynchronize() requirement

Tags: c, cuda

I have a cuda program like this :

```
for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
  if (i%2 == 0) {
    bind_x(x) // bind x to texture
    kernel_code<<A,B>>(M,x,y) // calculate y = M*x
  }
  else {
    bind_x(y)
    kernel_code<<A,B>>(M,y,x) // calculate x = M*y
  }

  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  if (i%2 == 0)
    unbind_x(x)
  else 
    unbind_x(y) // unbind x from texture
}
```

I heard that if I do not put `cudaThreadSynchronize();` cpu will continue to run without waiting for the kernel to end so ... Should I call `cudaThreadSynchronize()` before unbind_x(). I try to run with& without, the result is the same ?!? (And in theory It shouldn't)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any CUDA operation (except special asynchronious operations) will cause `cudaThreadSynchronize()` automatically. So, results should be the same.

Comment: Adding to that... "asynchronous operations" include the cudaMemcpyAsync family but also, importantly, other kernel launches.

Comment: Of course. It's naturally that if kernel_code<<>>() running in async mode, then the other kernels will also run in async. Thank you for addition.

Comment: However my bind and unbind is not kernel call. in kernel I have to fetch x from the texture memory while it may be unbind already if there is no synchronize

Comment: Sorry texture binding also asynchronous, so It will be queue